# Differentiate Tags: [remix], [remix.run]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

"Remix" can stand for:

- Remix.run which is a [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript)/[JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) web application framework, or
- Remix IDE, which is an IDE for [Ethereum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethereum) [smart contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_contract) development, or
- something else that I don't know about.

Currently, the [remix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remix) tag description is for the Remix IDE, but is often confused and thus co-occurs with the [remix.run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remix.run) tag.

Suggestions:

- Create a new [remix-ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remix-ide) tag meant to replace the [remix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remix) tag.
- Existing posts with the [remix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remix) tag should instead have the [remix-ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remix-ide) tag.
- Remove the ambiguous [remix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remix) tag.

Comment: Added suggestion: Correctly tag `remix` questions about `remix-run` library with `remix.run` tag.

Comment: correctly tag the `remix-run` questions then rename the `remix` to `remix-ide` to prevent any further misuse